# Singleton instance keeps on creating new instances in Go

Tags: go, redis

I am using redis to store sessions for my Go simple web app. 
For this, I only want a single session to access the redis connection at a time. 
I searched up on implementing singleton objects in Go and followed. 
This is the code I'm currently implementing:

### Redis connection:

```
package Datab

import (
    "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
)

type cache struct {
    Conn redis.Conn
}

var singleCache *cache = nil

func GetSessionCache() *cache {

    if singleCache == nil {

        singleCache := &cache{}
        singleCache.Conn, _ = redis.DialURL("redis://localhost")
        // ^ SINGLECACHE IS NOT NIL HERE.

    }
    return singleCache
    // ^ SAYS THIS IS NIL!

}
```

---

### Redis Implementation:

```
package Handler

import (
    Datab "videodoox/DB" // this file contains the redis connection implementation
)

connStru := *Datab.GetSessionCache()
cache := connStru.Conn

connStru2 := *Datab.GetSessionCache()
cache2: = connStru.Conn
// ^ THIS CONNECTION HERE IS A COMPLETELY NEW INSTANCE.
```

---

Everytime I get the connection, the redis connection file creates a new instance of the connection. 
How do I create a new connection once and just return that connection everytime?
Thanks!

Comment: `singleCache := &cache{}` => This is a short variable declaration which creates a new local var, shadowing the global one. Use assignment: `singleCache = &cache{}`. Also this is not safe for concurrent use. Best would be to init `singleCache` in a package `init()` function (or use `once.Do()` if you need deferred init).

Comment: @icza Oh shit I'm so dumb! That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot. Yes, I'm planning to use mutex to lock my threads and make it thread safe.

Comment: Note well the Redigo [documentation on concurrency](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#hdr-Concurrency).  You will need to use a mutex to control access to the connection methods or change the `cache` field to a pool.

Comment: try use that http://marcio.io/2015/07/singleton-pattern-in-go/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments to the initial question solve the issue, but just to provide a complete solution your code can look like:

```
package Datab

import (
    "sync"

    "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
)

type cache struct {
    Conn redis.Conn
}

var singleCache *cache
var initOnce sync.Once

func GetSessionCache() *cache {
    initOnce.Do(func() {
        singleCache := &cache{}
        singleCache.Conn, _ = redis.DialURL("redis://localhost")
    })

    return singleCache
}
```

Just a couple of extra notes:

- No need to specify `nil` as an initial value of pointers, zero value for them is `nil` by default (`var singleCache *cache` vs `var singleCache *cache = nil`).
- You should handle potential error returned by `redis.DialURL` and not just skip it with `_`.